# Work out percentage split of values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I am struggling to work out a way to get a percentage split between some returned values in SQL.

[image]

Using the above values for example, I need to first add them together to get a total, then find out what percentage of the total each of these are.

I am bringing these values from a temp table I created, named #Temp1

The script should be compatible with SQL Server 2005

I've been searching over the internet and can't find anything that suits this particular case.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a recent version of SQL Server, you can use the `over` clause:

```
select  AssetValue
,       100.0 * AssetValue / sum(AssetValue) over () as Percentage
from    #Temp1
```

For older versions of SQL Server:

```
select  AssetValue
,       100.0 * AssetValue / 
        (
        select  sum(AssetValue)
        from    #Temp1
        ) as Percentage
from    #Temp1
```

[Example for both at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/82a5f9/3/1)